# How to extract words used for Doc2Vec

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, doc2vec

I am preparing a Doc2Vec model using tweets. Each tweet's word array is considered as a separate document and is labeled as "SENT_1", SENT_2" etc.

```
taggeddocs = []
for index,i in enumerate(cleaned_tweets):
    if len(i) > 2: # Non empty tweets
        sentence = TaggedDocument(words=gensim.utils.to_unicode(i).split(), tags=[u'SENT_{:d}'.format(index)])
        taggeddocs.append(sentence)

# build the model
model = gensim.models.Doc2Vec(taggeddocs, dm=0, alpha=0.025, size=20, min_alpha=0.025, min_count=0)

for epoch in range(200):
    if epoch % 20 == 0:
        print('Now training epoch %s' % epoch)
    model.train(taggeddocs)
    model.alpha -= 0.002  # decrease the learning rate
    model.min_alpha = model.alpha  # fix the learning rate, no decay
```

I wish to find tweets similar to a given tweet, say "SENT_2". How?

I get labels for similar tweets as:

```
sims = model.docvecs.most_similar('SENT_2')
for label, score in sims:
    print(label)
```

It prints as:

```
SENT_4372
SENT_1143
SENT_4024
SENT_4759
SENT_3497
SENT_5749
SENT_3189
SENT_1581
SENT_5127
SENT_3798
```

But given a label, how do I get original tweet words/sentence? E.g. what are the tweet words of, say, "SENT_3497". Can I query this to Doc2Vec model?

Answer (score 1):

Gensim's Word2Vec/Doc2Vec models don't store the corpus data – they only examine it, in multiple passes, to train up the model. If you need to retrieve the original texts, you should populate your own lookup-by-key data structure, such as a Python dict (if all your examples fit in memory).

Separately, in recent versions of gensim, your code will actually be doing 1,005 training passes over your `taggeddocs`, including many with a nonsensically/destructively negative `alpha` value.

- By passing it into the constructor, you're telling the model to train itself, using your parameters and defaults, which include a default number of `iter=5` passes.
- You then do 200 more loops. Each call to `train()` will do the default 5 passes. And by decrementing `alpha` from 0.025 by 0.002 199 times, the last loop will use an effective `alpha` of 0.025-(200*0.002)=-0.375 - a negative value essentially telling the model to make a large correction in the opposite direction of improvement each training-example.

Just use the `iter` parameter to choose the desired number of passes. Let the class manage the `alpha` changes itself. If supplying the corpus when instantiating the model, no further steps are necessary. But if you don't supply the corpus at instantiation, you'll need to do `model.build_vocab(tagged_docs)` once, then `model.train(tagged_docs)` once.